# Why does my iPod Touch show Spotlight differently?

Tags: ipod-touch, ios, spotlight

I have an iPod Touch 5th gen (latest). After I upgraded to iOS 8.2, the Spotlight display looks like the following. Instead of the icons fading out to nearly invisible (as it does on my iPad and an iPhone 4S I tried), the icons are shown in chunky black and white.

What's going on here? Why does this happen on my iPod Touch, but it works correctly on both older and newer hardware? Is this simply a bug in iOS 8.2? Does this happen for anybody else?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this happen when I ran a beta version of iOS (8.0 beta 3 iirc). A reboot sometimes fixed it, but it kept coming back. The next beta fixed it for me.

Try rebooting, and check your accessibility options for greyscale (I have it in the triple-click home button menu, which I guessed was the culprit). Try disabling all accessibility options.

If you really want this gone and the above answers don't work, try a factory restore.

Comment: A reboot fixed it, thanks! I did have a few accessibility options set but none of them made any difference before or after the reboot.

Comment: Glad it was fixed!